# How to clear my ArrayList is size if 100 in this scenario:

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

My ultimate goal is to achieve batch processing of lines in an Executor Service. I have the following snippet of code:

```
while ((bLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    // We will use an array to hold 100 lines, so that we can batch process in a
    // single thread
    batchArray.add(bLine);
    switch (batchArray.size()) {
        case 100:
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(new LocalThreadPoolExecutor(batchArray, closeableHttpClient, httpPost));
            futures.add(future);
           // batchArray.clear() <--- point of failure
            break;
        default:
            logger.info("Batch size in switch: "+batchArray.size());

    }
}
```

Now if I do an `batchArray.clear()` in the `case 100` I get a concurrentModificationException. Unable to determine how can I reinit the array list and send 100 lines to my executor as they are read from file.

below is the stacktrace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at consumer.ril.com.LocalThreadPoolExecutor.run(LocalThreadPoolExecutor.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I get thie exception in my `LocalThreadPoolExecutor` class when I try to read the batchArray, which is passed in the constructor of this class.

Comment: It helps if you can post the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't clear the `batchArray` while your threads are working on it.

Comment: Added the stacktrace!

Comment: @Tom any hints on how can I batch process here otherwise?

Comment: can you put the batchArray code in a synchronized block?

Comment: Wait until all threads finished. You're working with futures, and they have a `isDone` method ... try to find a way using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution -- you need pass to LocalThreadPoolExecutor copy of array and clean original array.

```
Future<?> future = executor.submit(new LocalThreadPoolExecutor(new ArrayList<>
(batchArray), closeableHttpClient, httpPost));
futures.add(future);
batchArray.clear();
```

Comment: This one is a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your object `batchArray` is passed by reference, see this for more details:
[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

As such your class `LocalThreadPoolExecutor` still has a reference to it and cannot be modified.

Either using a `clone` or making the parameter `final` should work.

Comment: I used a clone and it works except for some warnings.

Comment: Looked at the implementation of `clone` and `Constructor(Collection)`, both seem to be intrinsically same. If you don't really need `batchArray` outside the loop, it might be better to implement as @nick-knysh has mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Some code is using list (Iterator) inside of LocalThreadPoolExecutor. At some point it realizes that list has been modified (cleared). You should use another copy of the list.

Since you don't need items in main thread, you could just explicitly create new list for each batch and pass it to processor:

Something like:

```
{   
...
     while ((batch = getNextBatch(bufferedReader, 100)).size() > 0) {
        futures.add(
            executor.submit(new LocalThreadPoolExecutor(batch, closeableHttpClient, httpPost))
        );
    }
...
}
```

get next batch:

```
List<String> getNextBatch(BufferedReader bReader, int batchSize) throws IOException {
    List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
    while (batch.size() < batchSize && (bLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
        batch.add(bLine);
    }
    return batch;
}
```